# django working with url parameters in views and templates

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.1+, with Python 3.6+.

in my urls.py, I have this url:

```
url('^member/(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/$', views.Member, name='member_data'),
```

Alone this works:

However from both the view:

```
def login(request):
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    username = User.objects.get(email=email)
    user = authenticate(request, username=username.username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth_login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        return reverse('member_data', {'username': username.username})
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        return redirect('login_page', {'error': 1})
```

and from the template (of note, this is a hardcode username to attempt to get the template the work):

```
<a href="{% url 'member_data' username='cheng' %}"><i class="ion ion-person"></i>My Service Record</a>
```

Results in a bad parameter error, in which I cannot resolve.  As such,
Any wisdom here would be greatly appreciated.  Is there a way this is supposed to read for both links?

the error that I'm starting with is from the login attempt:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_action/

Django Version: 2.1b1
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mptt',
 'svcrecord']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/sinistersparrow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/sinistersparrow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/sinistersparrow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/sinistersparrow/PycharmProjects/ifthqcom/svcrecord/views.py" in login
  36.         return reverse('member_data', {'username': username.username})

File "/Users/sinistersparrow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  30.     resolver = get_resolver(urlconf)

Exception Type: TypeError at /login_action/
Exception Value: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

And this is the error when going to the page directly:

## UPDATE #1...

the template seems to be working now.  still dealing with the view.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full error/traceback?

Comment: done.  thanks much.

Comment: Ha, for the reverse, you need to use `kwargs={..}`, so pass it to the kwargs parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`reverse(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) parameter has as signature:

> ```
> reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None
> ```

Now it is of course the `kwargs` we are interested in. But with a call like:

```
return reverse('member_data', {'username': username.username})
```

we actually pass the *dictionary* to the `urlconf` parameter, and this does not expect a dictionary.

We can however pass it to the `kwargs` parameter, by passing it to a *named* parameter, like:

```
return reverse('member_data', kwargs={'username': username.username}))
```

You furthermore **need to wrap it in a [`redirect(..)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)** to redirect the browser to this URL:

```
return redirect(reverse('member_data', kwargs={'username': username.username})))
```

Django however accepts that the `redirect(..)` contains a view(name) and parameters directly as well, like:

```
return redirect('member_data', username=username.username)
```

Comment: @arcee123: not to redirect, then you need to wrap the result (the URL) into a `redirect` response.

Comment: so my intent here is to just go to the member page with the username.  what's the best way to do that?

Comment: That is aweSOME!!!  I will accept in 30 seconds (when it allows).  THANKS MUCH!!!